# Inability to divide because of initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I apologize in advanced for my confusion, however, in my ODE textbook, it gives the following example:

$$\frac {dy}{dt} = (1+y)t$$ with initial value of $y(0) = -1$.

I am confused with this question because although from my understanding, there is definitely a solution to this equation, $$y=ke^\frac{t^2}{2}-1,$$ taken by dividing both sides by $(1+y)$, multiplying both sides by $dt$, and finally integrating both sides. With $k=0$, $$y=0e^\frac{t^2}{2}-1.$$ Then, utilizing $y(0)=-1$, solving the equation, $$y=0e^\frac{0^2}{2}-1 = 0(1)-1 = -1.$$ Given this, ultimately the solution to the initial-value is $$y = -1.$$

However, my textbook states that even dividing both sides of the differential equation by $(1+y)$ is impossible because then the differential equation would be undefined at $y(0) = -1$, however, even looking the solution up online, it seems that the solution does indeed exist? I would appreciate any and all help on this. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use separation of variables based on your comment (also, that's consistent with separation of variables being taught much earlier than, for example, integrating factors).

Notice that If you plug in $y(0) = -1$ you get that $y'(0) = 0$ and thus $y$ is not changing at this instant. This is an equilibrium solution. That is $y(t) = 0$.

I think the thing you're supposed to take away from this problem is that for any separable equation, if the initial condition precludes division, then you have an equilibrium solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because $y(0)= -1, y+ 1$ is $0$ AT $x= 0$ so we cannot divide by $y+ 1$ AT $x= 0$.  But we can do that to solve for $y(x)$ for all other $x$ and then extend the solution to $x= 0$ "by continuity".